# Notify nearby users in cloud functions using geofirestore

Tags: function, cloud, geofirestore

I have 2 firestore collections - `crews/{crew}/clients` and `crews/{crew}/pros`. If a new client registers and a new document is created, I want to search collection `pros` for pros working the matching sector and living within 5 km (of the new client), and send notification to the pros filtered. In order to implement that in cloud functions,
I installed geofirestore using npm, saved `crews/{crew}/pros` like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwAFO.png

but after executing this function, I have error message on cloud functions console like this;

`Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array`

Is there anything wrong with my firestore data structure? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this data structure was correct, because I could get notification to work with this data structure. I tried another structure like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtB5X.jpg
However, it gave me another error.